# Arrow keys on custom keyboard

Tags: android

I've been trying to add arrow keys to the SoftKeyboard example from the SDK, without success:
Added this to the keyboard xml (qwerty.xml):

I can see the extra keys on the keyboard, but when I click them I get squares.
Can anyone tell why?

I googled for it but could not find any answer, this seem to be correct - but does not work.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it. I needed to handle the key down and do this:

```
    CharSequence txt = getCurrentInputConnection().getTextBeforeCursor(1000, 0);
    int len = txt.length();

    if ( len > 1 )
    {
        switch (arrow)
        {
        case KEY_LEFT:
            len--;
            break;
        case KEY_RIGHT:
            len++;
            break;
        case KEY_UP: case KEY_DOWN: //TBD
            break;
        }

        getCurrentInputConnection().setSelection(len, len);     
    }
```

yakobom